# Windows Forms - pass argument between form and control

Tags: c#, winforms, controls

In my C# Windows Forms project I have:

- *mycontrol* (it's keyboard)
- *myform* (it's layout for textbox, and mycontrol )

I would like to run some code which is in *myform*, but by pressing button in *mycontrol* )

For example:

When I press Backspace button in *mycontrol* I just use Button Event

```
SendKeys.Send("{BACKSPACE}");
```

and *myform* textbox know that I press Backspace.

But I have some custom buttons (functional) and those buttons should be define in *myform*

for example in *myform* I have:

```
private void btnOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DoSomething();

        }
```

The whole problem is - how to Run *myform* btnOK_Click or DoSomething from *mycontrol*

UPDATE #2:

Nothing happens while pressing D0, NullReference when I delete checking if it's null.

internal partial class myForm : BaseForms
    {
        public myForm() {
            InitializeComponent();
            ShowMyControl();
        }

```
private void ShowMyControl(){
    KeyboardControl myControl = new KeyboardControl();
  myControl.KeyboardKeyPressed += new Action<string>(OnMyControlKeyPressed);
  this.Controls.Add(myControl);
}

private void OnMyControlKeyPressed(string key)
{
    switch (key)
    {
        case "D0":
            MessageBox.Show("A");
            break;
        case "D1":
            MessageBox.Show("B");
            break;
        default:
            MessageBox.Show("C");
            break;
    }
}
...
}
```

and

```
public partial class KeyboardControl : UserControl
    {
    public event Action<string> KeyboardKeyPressed;
    ...
    private void HandlingMouseClick1(Point PressedItem)
        {
         ...
          case Keys.D0:
                            if (KeyboardKeyPressed != null)
                                KeyboardKeyPressed("D0");
                            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Not sure if i understand your question can't you just call the method in the same way as you determine the condition for `SendKeys` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try out the below approach
inside MyForm

```
    public class MyForm : Form
    {
    //.ctor
    MyForm() { }

    private void ShowMyControl(){
      MyControl myControl = new MyControl();
      myControl.KeyboardKeyPressed += new Action<string>(OnMyControlKeyPressed);
      this.Controls.Add(myControl);
    }

    private void OnMyControlKeyPressed(string key)
    {
     switch(key)
      {
       case "D0" :
        DoSomething();
        break;
       case "D1" :
        DoSomethingElse();
        break;
       default :
        SendKeys(key);
        break;
      }
    }
}

/*MyControl*/

namespace Keyboards
{
  public class MyControl : Control
  {

    public event Action<string> KeyboardKeyPressed;

    private void HandlingMouseClick(Point PressedItem)
    {
        if(KeyboardKeyPressed != null)
           KeyboardKeyPressed(PressedItem.ToString());
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It looks good. But I have some issue. I am trying to run KeyboardKeyPressed("D1"); from MyControl with result NullReference.

Comment: Ok it works! I just change to this.myControl.KeyboardKeyPressed += new Action<string>(OnMyControlKeyPressed); instead of craeting new control in ShowMyControl()

Answer (score 3):

In MyForm_Load, or anywhere else if you dynamically initialize your MyControl, you can add something like `MyControl.Click += new System.KeyEventHandler(this.MyControl_Click)` and place a method called

```
private void MyControl_Click(sender object, KeyEventArgs e)
{
   ... //Find out which key was pressed, proceed.
}
```

in MyForm. The method will be called when the Click event is raised.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `delegate` and pass it to the constructor of your second form.

```
public delegate void MyDelegate(Object SomeData);
```

You'll need to create a delegate according to the method's signature you want to use.

```
MyDelegate del = form1.DoSomething;
Form2 form2 = new Form2(..., del);
```

Then you can encapsulate a method from your *form1* and pass it to *form2* and then invoke it in *form2*.

```
public Form2(..., MyDelegate del){ }

del.Invoke();
```

Look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173171%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) for delegates.

Comment: I did not provide an example, just a hint. Check on `delegates` and how to use them. Define a delegate in your form1, and pass it to form2 in the constructor of form2.

Comment: No overload for 'DoSomething' matches delegate myForm.MyDelegate

Comment: You will need to adapt the delegate to your needs. You will need to define the signature of the delegate accordingly. If you have no return-value and pass no data it is `public delegate void MyDelegate();`

Comment: Well it won't work. I can't use form1 name. I should pass whole function from myform to mycontrol. Not calling myform methods from mycontrol. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Your control should expose an event that the form can then subscribe to and act upon.

Give your event a meaningful name. If your control contains a Search button and the user clicks it, let your control fire an event called `SearchButtonClicked`, for instance.

Then the form can contain a method that subscribes to the `SearchButtonClicked` event, and that code will then be executed whenever the user clicks the Search button.

See also the [Events Tutorial on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

Comment: or more generically CustomButtonClicked and pass an enumeration in the event args.

Comment: JamesB, that would certainly work, however (my 2 cents) that would be a bit less readable.

Comment: I think it would depend on how many buttons there are. Less than 5 I think without the enumeration would be more readable, with lots I think the enum would help.

Answer (score 0):

Add a reference of MyForm in your MyControl class

```
class MyControl
{
    MyForm _form=null;
    MyControl(MyForm form)
    {
        _form=form;
    }

    void DoSth()
    { 
        if(_form!=null)
           _form.DoSomething();
    }
}
```

Comment: Terrible design, sorry... A control should not have knowledge about who uses it. With "who" I mean the form it is on or the other control(s) that it is a part of... This violates the abstraction principle.

Comment: Ridiculous. You will have no flexibility if you just keep every design pattern in mind without looking at the detailed requirement. You comment is not constructive, in my view, this is not very useful to bash.d at all.

Comment: Sorry you feel that way, David. Please do make the effort to learn proper object orientation, and you will see that this "design" makes no sense at all. There is no way anyone can maintain large projects that are designed in the way you propose above. I find my comment quite constructive, maybe it is not what you wanted to read, but if this helps you and others in any way to avoid the common mistake of violating basic design principles, then it has served its purpose.

Comment: Forget about your theory. I don't see any design pattern that can work for all scenarios. When we talk about a design pattern, we always discuss it in some context. Bidirectional communication is sometimes needed, not always a bad design.

Comment: This is not a theory, this is about proper engineering. Bidirectional communication is one thing - completely unnecessary in this case, because you can solve this with a proper event design, which makes it reusable - but tight coupling like this is only a good idea for POC objects that you have to finish in a rush and then throw away. Check out http://www.jasoncoffin.com/cohesion-and-coupling-principles-of-orthogonal-object-oriented-programming and many other articles and books about proper O-O, I think you'll find it enlightening. I know my world opened up when I learned about decent design.

Comment: You like to use such words like "complete", "terrible", "no sense", "only", these are too subjective or absolute. I don't believe there is a silverbullet design pattern that should be used every time in every circumstances. You comments seem overkill for this post.

Comment: I agree with Roy, given that anyone has taken the time and effort to create a control instead of just writing code in form, why would you want to limit the use of the control to only that form?

Comment: @JamesB, then it would make no sense to call myform's method in mycontrol, do you agree? We are talking about the solution, given this specific requirement. What Roy and you are arguing, is on problem description, not on the solution?

Comment: Do you add a reference to a form on a button to tell the form that the button was clicked?